# Need help creating controller variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails app allows users to create "connections" that describes their relationship with other users. Users can comment on other users' blog posts (called "works" here) and, for each comment made on a blog post, I want to show the users' relationship to the author. I'm having trouble creating the instance variable in the works controller.

Here's what I have so far in the show action in the works controller:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @workuser = @work.user_id
  @connections = Connection.where(user_id: @workuser, otheruser_id: UNKNOWN).all
  @comment = @work.comments.build
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC").where(work_id: @work).all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
 end
```

I need help with the `@connections` instance variable, specifically what to assign the `otheruser_id:` parameter. **I know for a fact that this needs to be the user_id of the user who posted a comment.** However, I'm stumped as to how to get this id.

Here are the model relationships:

```
work.rb-  belonts_to :user, has_many :comments
user.rb-  has_many :works, has_many :comments, has_many :connections
connection.rb- belongs_to :user
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other information. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

EDIT: Simplified version of the view code that populates the comments (the user, the relationship to the author, and the comment content):

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

  <%= link_to comment.user.full_name, comment.user if comment.user %>,                                                  
  <%= @connections.description %>
  <%= @comment.content %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how connections are created? For instance.. if there are 2 users (steve(id:1), bruce(id:2)). will the connection records be like this? `[<# Connection 1, user_id=>1, Other_user=>2, :description=>'friend' >,<# Connection 2, user_id=>2, Other_user=>1, :description=>'friend' >]`. So are connections two way or one way? i.e steve may call bruce a friend but bruce may call steve a colleague.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. Connections are one way. I can call someone a friend but the other user doesn't have to accept/deny it. A row in that table would look like: id, user_id (the user creating the connection), otheruser_id (the subject of the connection), description

Comment: So that means the author may not have a connection with some of the commentators?

Comment: Alright. Let us know if my solution worked. ::) all the best.

Comment: It worked great! I can't thank you enough for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill update yo on the instance variable once you answer my comment. But Bachan's answer should do it if its two way.

EDIT:

After what you said about one way relationships I think you should not create `@connections` instance variable.

Instead define a method in the user.rb model like this:

```
def get_connection otheruser
 Connection.where(:user_id=>self.id,:otheruser_id=>otheruser.id).first
end
```

Then in the view.....
So you wanna display all the comments like:

> Commentator Name
>
> Connection between commentator and work author
>
> comment content

Alright to do that you can do this:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= link_to comment.user.full_name, comment.user if comment.user %>                                                 
  <%= @work.user.get_connection(comment.user).description unless  @work.user.get_connection(comment.user).nil? %>
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @workuser = @work.user_id
  @comment = @work.comments.build
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!! I'm new to Rails and I never thought to define a method in the model itself. I was wondering why it was so difficult to define this all in the controller! Should I always look to create an instance variable and then look to creating a custom method as a last resort? How do you know which is the best way to solve a problem?

Comment: The Golden rule is to keep the controllers thin. All your custom queries like finding connection etc should have a method in the model so you can access them like normal attributes in the Controllers. Just Follow this... :) thank you

Comment: Noted! Thanks again for the help! I really appreciate the thorough explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with

```
@connections = Connection.where("user_id = ? OR otheruser_id = ?", @workuser, @workuser)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This might work but now I'm getting an error in the view: `undefined method `description`. I posted the view code in the question. What's the best way to implement this?